# More pythonic way to select only some elements from the sublists of a nested list

Tags: python

I am doing

```
result = []
for item in tmp_result:
    tmp = []
    tmp.append(item[0])
    tmp.append(item[2])
    tmp.append(item[3])
    result.append(tmp)
```

How can I make this code more Pythonic?

Answer (score 4):

To generalize:

```
indexes = 0, 2, 3
result = [[item[i] for i in indexes] for item in tmp_result]
```

See the Python docs on [list comprehensions](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions).

Answer (score 3):

I would probably do it this way:

```
result = [[item[0], item[2], item[3]] for item in tmp_result]
```

Answer (score 2):

If you don't have any constrains you could use numpy for this. It's more efficient and more elegant, all you need is:

```
>> import numpy
>> a = numpy.array([[1,2,3], [1,2,3]])
>> a[:,1]
array([2,2])
>> a[:,[2,3]]
array([2,3], [2,3])
```

Answer (score 0):

Try list comprehensions:

```
result.extend([ [i[0], i[2], i[3]] for i in tmp_result])
```

Comment: Why would you use `extend`? `result` is created immediately before the loop.